# Page Object Pattern for web testing

Tags: nightwatch.js, intern, pageobjects, web-testing, webdriver-io

I'm looking into several javascript frameworks that can be used for e2e automated testing, mainly: Webdriver.io, theIntern and Nightwatch.

And I really want to get some feedback from developers on which framework could best support the page object pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intern supports that pattern (and it's a general enough pattern that I'd assume the other two do as well). There are a couple of ways to implement it with Intern.

One possibility is mentioned in the [Intern Guide](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#page-objects). The Command object used to control a remote browser is wrapped in another class that adds page-specific functionality.

A different style of implementation that's a bit more flexible is described [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2016/04/19/command-helpers/). Setting up a Command wrapper to allow more than one custom call to be chained can be tricky. The second implementation uses Command helper functions, which can be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the main pain points I've experienced with various framework page object implementations:

1. *must* allow creation of elements/locators *once* and not repeat them elsewhere (DRY)
2. how it handles a `basePage` (ie. page elements/methods not specific to a single page (eg. `hitEnter()`))
3. how it handles repeated elements across pages (eg. a nav bar that exists on multiple pages)
4. does it allow for *readable* tests

Opinion will certainly factor into these... which is fine. Answer these questions for your framework of choice, and you'll have your answer.